# **Uipath - how to search an object by full text**

Tags: uipath

I am new on `UIpath` and need some help.
I want to select a specific object (`AA`) from a list in a software:

List:

```
AAT

AA
```

The order differ from time to time. We are using the `click text` tool to select the `AA` object, however the `RPA` selects the `AAT` because the `AA` letters appear first on list.

Any tips? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your issue in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code, commands or screen shots which describe your problem. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially for [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: Can you see the uploaded image? We only have recorded steps. Basically we have a list with some objects (AAT and AA). We want that RPA recognizes the element (AA) and click it. The problem is RPA selects the first element which contains the similar letters (AAT) and not for full text as we want.

Comment: Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try the `Click` activity instead of `Click Text`. In the properties pane, change the Selector accordingly; here is an example where IIS Express is selected from the Add/Remote Programs window.

[image: Click Activity Selector]